# Pandas: How to make np arrays match dataframe's dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

After flicking through some related posts, I'm afraid I still was unable to come up with a solution to my problem.

I want to add an extra column to a dataframe (data2) which is a copy of the original dataframe imported from a csv. This new column shall populate its values based on the values of another column named 'world_rank'. After going through some posts on applying conditional structures, I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("data/cwurData.csv")
#Creating a copy of the dataframe
data2 = data
#Creaating the new variable/column/index
qoe = data.groupby('world_rank')
#Creating the conditional structure
conditions = [(data2['world_rank'] < 100).any(), ((data2['world_rank'] > 100).any and (data2['world_rank']< 300)).any(), (data2['world_rank'] > 300).any()]
choices = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
data2['qoe'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
#Inserting the new column in position 5
data2.insert(5, 'qoe', qoe)
#Checking new variable and values are added as per design
print(data2.axes)
data2.head(n=500)
```

However, I encountered this error message `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. I gather this stems from the fact that the lenght of mi np.select array doesn't match the dataframe's dimension. Would you be so kind to let me know how could I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just as an FYI: `data2 = data` does **not** create a copy of your dataframe, just another reference to it. To copy it use `data2 = data.copy()`

Comment: Thanks @NolantheNerd, noted!